# docker compose permission denial

Tags: python, docker, docker-compose, cassandra

I'm getting this error every time i try to run docker-compose up -d :

```
<urlopen error [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/etc/httpd/conf/mime.types'>
```

i'm on manjaro latest version, docker desktop works fine, docker info as well and I added the user to docker group.

my docker-compose file:

```
version: '3'
services:
  cass:
      image: cassandra:3.11.8
      container_name: cass
      ports:
        - "9042:9042"
      environment:
        - "MAX_HEAP_SIZE=1024M"
        - "HEAP_NEWSIZE=128M"
      #restart: always
      volumes:
        - ./out/cassandra_data:/var/lib/cassandra
      #healthcheck:
        #test: ["CMD", "cqlsh", "-u cassandra", "-p cassandra" ,"-e describe keyspaces"]
        #interval: 15s
        #timeout: 10s
        #retries: 10
```

EDIT:
deleting the file resulted in a fix, kinda. But now i got another error when pulling Cassandra from the registry:

```
dial tcp: lookup registry-1.docker.io on [::1]:53: read udp [::1]:41259->[::1]:53: read: connection refused
```

EDIT2: Linux is the worst thing to code on tbh

Comment: Is that error coming from Compose directly, or from inside your container?  Do you have any code or container setup that mentions an `/etc/httpd` directory at all?

Comment: no container starts because of the error, and the docker compsoe file has no /etc/httpd, i however deleeted the mime.types file and now i got another error: ERROR: Get "https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/": dial tcp: lookup registry-1.docker.io on [::1]:53: read udp [::1]:41259->[::1]:53: read: connection refused

Comment: it seems like deleting the file fixed it but it stops when it tried to pull Cassandra from the registry.

Answer (score 0):

Try running docker-compose using sudo:

```
sudo docker-compose up -d
```

If this works, and you want to run docker without sudo you need to add your user to the docker group as described here: https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/linux-postinstall/

Comment: i already tried that, even logging in as a su didn't work

Comment: It doesn't look like a docker error, maybe more permissions within manjaro. Can you set the file it is trying to read to readable, i.e:

sudo chmod a+r /etc/httpd/conf/mime.types

Comment: i tried but to no avail, even docker pull is not working for some reason and throwing a udp error, do you have a discord or something i'll try to share my screen